# C# Find next occurrence of a certain string in a list

Tags: c#, android, list, listview

I'm trying to find the next occurrence of a string in a list that is created dynamically. First I create the list with buttons that save text to a txt file and then divide the file with "," in to a list and by clicking items in the list, I update a textview item next to the list.

<del>The `var it = lstv.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);` gives the position on where to start searching for the next string. The next string is one of two possibilities.</del>

**List creation**

```
string content;
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filename))
{
content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
content = content.TrimEnd(',');
char[] delimiterChars = { ',' }; 
data = content.Split(delimiterChars);
var myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.TextViewItem, data);
lstv.Adapter = myAdapter;
```

The suggestions I have found only get the first or last occurrence, but I have multiple occurrences of the values and I need to get next occurrence from the clicked position

**Edit:**
Should have mentioned there are X number of items between the the starting position and the string I would want get.

**Edit2:**

The list is something like this:

```
String 1 or String 2 
String x
String x
String x
String x
String 1 or String 2
String x
String X
String 1 or String 2
```

The amount of String x between the next String 1 or 2 I want to get varies. When the user clicks on String 1/2 the program needs to find the next position where the value is String 1 or String 2.

<del>Oh yes it gives an item. And when I get the next required string I can get position of that item and what I need to do next. Sorry if I'm a bit too unclear.</del>

**Edit3:**

**OnListItemClick method**

```
protected void OnListItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var it = lstv.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);
        View v = (sender as View);
        int pos = lstv.GetPositionForView(v);
        if (it.ToString().Equals("String1") || it.ToString().Equals("String2")
        {
                /*while (!it.ToString().Equals("String1") || !it.ToString().Equals("String2"))
                {
                    it = lstv.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position + 1);
                    lstv.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);
                    //lstv.SetSelection(e.Position);
                }*/

                //it = lstv.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position - 1);
                int itt = lstv.SelectedItemPosition;
                txtv.Text = it.ToString();
                txtv2.Text = pos.ToString();
                txtv3.Text = itt.ToString();                
        }
        else
        {
        // Some code here
        }
    }
```

I try to get the position with `View v = (sender as View);` but it always returns the position as -1 no matter what item I click in the list.

In the list if I click for example a second occurrence of String 1 the program should find the next item that is either String 1 or String 2. When found, that should give position of the item.

The while loop works if I only search for String 1 or 2 but not if I search for both. I'm probably doing a lot of things wrong, but if I could get a little help on what look for I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while loop should solve the issue...

Answer (score 1):

> The while loop works if I only search for String 1 or 2 but not if I search for both.

Remember : !(a || b) is the same as (!a && !b)

Therefore you should write:

```
while (!it.ToString().Equals("String1") && !it.ToString().Equals("String2")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be :

> return lstv.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position++);

?

Comment: Check my edit. This will just get next item in the list.

Comment: Would you use a while loop ?

Comment: Hmm it just goes to an infinite loop if I use both of the required strings. With one searchable string it works though.

Comment: Maybe you should write again your question because I am reading it again and again and don't understand. You wrote "I'm trying to find the next occurrence of a string" is it next occurrence of string1 or string2 ? You wrote "The var it = lstv.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);gives the position" but it gives an item and not a position...

Comment: You were correct with the while loop. There were some problems in my code, I'll edit a working code snippet in later. Thank you!